# How to remap clear buffer to delete all lines in Iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

I would like to map the `CMD K` (clear buffer) keyboard shortcut to use `CTRL L` (delete all lines).

I have tried sending txt (ex: clear) or hex values, but it only pastes the text in the buffer and I still have to hit the `Enter` button.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select `Send Hex Code` and enter `0x230c` which is CTRL + L.

[image: Screenshot for sending CTRL+L when pressing CMD+K]